# How to convert a blender material to a simple color in mass?

Tags: modeling, texturing, materials, node-editor, objects

I have around 200 small spheres that are a part of a 3D data plot and I want to color them based on their z position. The way this is done is by making a material that uses a color ramp based on the z coordinate of the object, and applying the material to every sphere.

The problem is that I want to export this to a glb/glTF and the color ramp node doesn’t function when exported. How can I convert my 1 material into a simple base color for every sphere? It is ok if every single sphere has a different material, its just that doing this by hand is very time consuming.

Thanks

Comment: @A T Please show your current material graph (with the color ramp node).

Answer (score 3):

You can get away with 1 material and 1 image texture if you use *Project from View* for the UV unwrap.

Material:
[image: material]

3D plot / cloud points:
[image: 3d plot]

Add a square plane for your point cloud and give it the same material. Bake the texture. Then select everything and UV unwrap (<kbd>U</kbd>) with *Project from View* in orthographical view (<kbd>Numpad 1</kbd>). Scale the UV islands to fit the gradient image vertically if needed. Done.

PS: Yes, the UV map is scary. Keep the spheres low-poly.

[image: uv unwrap]